# how do I reinstall a video driver

Tags: drivers, video, reset

I've read similar questions on this topic but they have no useful answers.

I need to reinstall the video driver becouse my external monitor is showing disturbing horizontal lines. Maybe reinstalling the drivers will solve the problem.

When I do lshw -c video, I get that the driver is i915.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before. The way I found that works for me, is to turn off mirroring, then auto-adjust your secondary monitor.